# How to select data where the last three characters are numbers?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table with a column having values like:

> AB123
> AB209
> ABQ52
> AB18C

I would like to extract rows whose last three characters are numbers. How can I do this?

The original table is more complicated, and I tried the "WHERE" clause with "AB___", which returned the above to me.

Comment: Digits, not numbers. (123 as a three-digit number.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of `SUBSTRING` and `REGEXP` like this:

```
SELECT yourcolumn FROM yourtable WHERE SUBSTRING(yourcolumn, -3) REGEXP '^[0-9]+$';
```

The `SUBSTRING` part will cut the last 3 characters of the column's value and the `REGEXP` condition will check whether this substring is numeric.

Comment: `'[0-9]{3}$'` should work without SUBSTRING.

Comment: Your query is not correct. It will return the rows where the value to be tested is 1-2-digit string (`'1'`, `'23'`, etc.)

Comment: In my opinion, this is not incorrect according to the author's question. But of course, you can add a condition on the length or do further modifications if you think this is required.

Comment: I think that the answer either must be universal or must completely describe additional requirements. Somebody else who have similar task may find this solution, but it may be not applicable to his particular task due to non-described restrictions - do you think that this is good situation?

Comment: Actually it works with '1' or '12', because `SUBSTRING(.., -3)` will return an empty string for them and the regex will not match it. But that behaviour is not clearly documented.